# My swipeview doesn't open first programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My project is in Xamarin Forms and i have a very simple code.

```
            <SwipeView x:Name="MainSwipe" BackgroundColor="#dcdde1">
                <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                    <SwipeItems Mode="Reveal">
                        <SwipeItemView>
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#208b55" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="20">
                                <Label Text="HITÉLET" Style="{x:StaticResource LabelLeftMenu}" x:Name="open_hitelet" Padding="10"/>
                                <Label Text="KULTÚRA" Style="{x:StaticResource LabelLeftMenu}" x:Name="open_kultura" Padding="10"/>
                                <Label Text="KÖZÉLET" Style="{x:StaticResource LabelLeftMenu}" x:Name="open_kozelet" Padding="10"/>
                                <Label Text="ÉLETMÓD" Style="{x:StaticResource LabelLeftMenu}" x:Name="open_eletmod" Padding="10"/>
                                <Label Text="GAZDASÁG" Style="{x:StaticResource LabelLeftMenu}" x:Name="open_gazdasag" Padding="10"/>
                                <Label Text="SZÍNES" Style="{x:StaticResource LabelLeftMenu}" x:Name="open_szines" Padding="10"/>
                                <Label Text="RÓLUNK" Style="{x:StaticResource LabelLeftMenu}" x:Name="open_rolunk" Padding="10"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </SwipeItemView>
                    </SwipeItems>
                </SwipeView.LeftItems>
           </SwipeView>
```

And i have a method to open left menu:

```
MainSwipe.Open(OpenSwipeItem.LeftItems);
```

But it isn't work perfectly.(does not open completely) [image]

Comment: Hi, do you mean that the second time swipview shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested with shared coed, it's interesting. It shows the same with yours. Maybe it's an issue of **SwipeView**.

**However**, I have a workaround to solve this. You could add `WidthRequest` for the child view of `SwipeItemView`. As follows:(set `WidthRequest="100"`)

```
<SwipeView x:Name="swipeView" HeightRequest="300">
    <SwipeView.LeftItems>
        <SwipeItems>
            <SwipeItemView>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#208b55"
                                Orientation="Vertical"
                                WidthRequest="100"
                                Margin="20">
                    ...
                </StackLayout>
            </SwipeItemView>
        </SwipeItems>
    </SwipeView.LeftItems>
```

The effect:

[image]

In addition, you could submit it as an issue [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues) in Github to follow it up there to know whether it has been sloved.